# How do I add more categories to Mac OS X Finder's sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder

My Finder sidebar has two categories: Favorites and Devices. How do I add more categories?

Answer (score 15):

It's not possible to add more categories (see picture). There are:

- Favorites:

  - For any subdirectory of the root directory
  - You can add custom links to folders (not files) via drag and drop
  - custom searches
- Shared:

  - Local Network, Servers, Back to my Mac, Time Capsule,...
- Devices:

  - Harddrives (internal/external), other storage media like CDs, devices like iPhones

[image]

However, there is a workaround which allows to add separators and changing icons.

Download the [icons here](http://cl.ly/8trB).

[image: Screenshot of separators]

Answer (score 0):

So this is a very old post. However, I haven't found the solution elsewhere, so for anyone else looking - here's how I got dividers into my sidebar (working in Mavericks 10.9.4):

1. Download the 'Lion-Sidebar-Separators-Tweak.dmg (from the icons link in gentmatt's post above)
2. Mount the .dmg and drag the 'SidebarSmartFolders.icns' to the 'Drop here - Resources' alias. You'll need to enter an admin password to edit that folder (it links to the package contents of the CoreTypes.bundle within the System/Library folder).
3. Copy the 'Smart Folders' folder to a sensible storage location.
4. Add one or more of the smart folders within that folder to your sidebar. The smart folder logo won't appear, and you'll just get the folder name appearing in the sidebar - i.e. a solid divider line.

Notes

- This will make all your smart folders in your sidebar lose the smart folder logo.
- Keep the 'Originals' folder from the .dmg in case you want to remove this tweak later.
- If you use smart folders a lot in the sidebar, there is also the option to use applications.

I hope this helps someone else looking for the same thing I was.

Cheers!

Comment: This doesn’t work on Sierra anymore.